# Code splitting in a React and Vite SSG UI library

Tags: reactjs, sass, vite, static-site-generation

I have spent hours going over Vite documentation and git-issues and tried a number of things but nothing seems to allow code splitting in SSG library mode.

This is really annoying as you want to be able to import a stand alone component with out including the entire library and CSS into the build of your application.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution ?